# datarow not showing all data

Tags: c#, datarow

I am having some problems with a datarow - all of the data is not showing?

I have this in file:

```
this.friendData = DatabaseClient.ReadDataTable("SELECT users.Id,users.username,users.motto,users.look,users.last_online FROM users JOIN friendships ON users.Id = friendships.user_two_id WHERE friendships.user_one_id = '" + num + "'");
```

and then another file this:

```
DataRow[] DataRow_ = Session.GetUser().Data.friendData.Select("id = 8");
```

and when i try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DataRow_[0]["username"]);
```

It print this: "gassu" but my username is "TestAccount"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DataRow_[0]["username"]);
```

Comment: Wtf.. It prints "gassu" and my username is "TestAccount" and print error: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: how many rows did you get?  Print out the count/length of the DataRow_.  Maybe more than 1 row is coming back???

Comment: you should post the exception including line # and the code.. there seems to be more code at work here.

Comment: i don't understand how you can see output AND get the cast error... need to see more.

Comment: you sure the DB your code is running against is the same as where you are "thinking" it is running?

Comment: It prints that "gassu" to console and then comes error: Specified cast is not valid. i tested it with id and it prints correct id and trow error Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: paste the entire exception, and paste the line that it is failing.  It cannot be failing on the Console.WriteLine as you are seeing output.  I cannot help you if you don't SHOW YOUR CODE.. lol

Comment: Ok fixed.. Error was because id is uint not int :D

Write.Int32(Convert.ToInt32((uint)dataRow["id"]));

Comment: Ok i forgot i renamed my test account to "gassu" xd